# How to package pom.xml dependencies into Docker image using Docker-Maven image as base?

Tags: maven, docker, pom.xml

I'm trying to package dependencies from a POM.xml file into a docker image during the image build phase but when I run my program it still downloads the maven dependencies.

The docker image I'm using as a base image is the official Docker-Maven image from carlossg.

The instructions state:
*The `$MAVEN_CONFIG` dir (default to `/root/.m2`) could be configured as a volume so anything copied there in a Dockerfile at build time is lost.
For that the dir `/usr/share/maven/ref/` is created, and anything in there will be copied on container startup to `$MAVEN_CONFIG`.  For that reason the dir `/usr/share/maven/ref/` exists, and anything in that directory will be copied on container startup to `$MAVEN_CONFIG`.*

And to add the following at to the Dockerfile:

```
COPY pom.xml /tmp/pom.xml
RUN mvn -B -f /tmp/pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml 
dependency:resolve
```

So my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-8
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY pom.xml /tmp/pom.xml
RUN mvn -f /tmp/pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml 
dependency:resolve
```

I then build the docker image using the following command:

`docker build -t [image_name] .`

I then upload the docker image to a docker repository and reference it in a gitlab-ci.yml file to run my tests. The tests build and run fine but all the dependencies are downloaded again which can take some time.

I'm following the README here from the official page:

`https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven`

Is there something missing from my Dockerfile? What else do I need to do to prevent the image from downloading all the dependencies again?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid that maven contacts the repository, run it with `-o` flag.

Comment: That doesn't work. It still needs to download the default maven dependencies and hence it fails.